# Python search fixed patterned texts in a long string

Tags: python-3.x

I need to extract a string of number from a long string,

Here is what my data look like:

```
{descripions: "Foo: bar\n Blah: Lahb\n Account Id: 12345678\n Dummy: data ..."}
```

I want to extract the `12345678` from the long string between `""`.

It follows some patterns:

1. The number of interests is always after `Account ID:`, with a space after colon.
2. The number of interests can be any digit
3. The number of interests is always followed by `\n`
4. The data `Account Id: 12345678` does not necessarily exist. In this case, I want the return null value `''` rather than error message

Any Regex or Code can help achieve this goal?

Comment: This looks a lot like JSON, in which case you should be using a parser, not regex.

Comment: It's JSON, I am very new to Python. What's a good parser that I can use? Thank you!

Comment: Python should ship with a native `json` library, which might already be able to do what you need.  Read up on that library for starters.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be like this:

```py
import re
json_data = {'descriptions': "Foo: bar\n Blah: Lahb\n Account Id: 12345678\n Dummy: data ..."}
text = json_data['descriptions']
match = re.findall(r'Account Id: (.\d+)\n',text)
result = None
if len(match) > 0:
    result = match[0]
print(result)
```